# Base SAS programming

Tags: sas, analytics

My dataset consists a variable named as "REPORTING_ENTITY" in the form of string. Now, from that variable i want create a new dataset which consist a observations with keywords as ('Bank','Loan','Cooperative','SBI','Insurance') from "REPORTING_ENTITY" also want that strings get deleted from original dataset. I did something like:

```
data class.sample;
set work.sample;
where REPORTING_ENTITY contains ('Bank','Loan','Cooperative','SBI','Insurance');
run;
```

This will create a new dataset with mentioned keywords but it will not get deleted from orignal dataset..

Comment: Can you post some example data and what you want the result to look like?  Do you want the search and replace to be case sensitive? Do you want to match whole words or partial words?  For example should "Citibank" be converted to "Citi"?

Comment: No... i want whole Citibank to be get removed from dataset

Comment: You missed the first part, posting sample data that reflects your question.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to overwrite the input dataset while simultaneously creating a new output dataset:

```
data class.sample
     work.sample;
set work.sample;
if REPORTING_ENTITY in ('Bank','Loan','Cooperative','SBI','Insurance') 
  then output class.sample;
  else output work.sample;
run;
```